# Regex ('foo'|'bar') notation

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regex to parse some time data, but my attempt is not matching as I would expect.  Here's my code:

```
import re
print re.findall("\d+:\d+ (am|pm)", "11:30 am - 2:20 pm")
```

This produces `['am', 'pm']`, not `['11:30 am', '2:20 pm']`, which is what I want.

I can produce the result that I want with `\d+:\d+ am|\d+:\d+ pm`, but that is a little blunt and I want to know why the other is not working?

Comment: `re.findall("(\d+):(\d+) (?:am|pm)", time_string)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem relates to capturing groups. If you want to have non-capturing alternation use the regex `\d+:\d+ (?:am|pm)`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little confused by the terminology... in this case don't I _want_ to capture the am/pm? Why is it included in the match if it isn't captured?

Comment: @TomRobbins: Everything that is matched is part of the match. Capturing groups only allow you to extract *part* of the match. If you actually want to have a constraint for the match but not match it, you can use lookahead.

Comment: By adding `:?` to the parens it becomes a non-capturing group. If you want to capture only the first part of the time then wrap that in parens. Like @sudomakeinstall2 offered you could add at capturing group to the numeric part if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't even need regular expressions to split this particular string. If applicable, you can use the regular [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> s = "11:30 am - 2:20 pm"
>>> s.split(" - ")
['11:30 am', '2:20 pm']
```

This, of course, does not enforce items to be "time"-like strings.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) (**emphasis mine**):

> `re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group.** Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.

You may use `re.finditer`:

```
seq = [m.string[m.start():m.end()] for m in re.finditer("\d+:\d+ (am|pm)", "11:30 am - 2:20 pm")]
# ['11:30 am', '2:20 pm']
```